# Como posso fazer um sistema de monitoramento?

Tags: c#, vb.net, monitoramento

Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma para uma empresa, e cheguei a uma dúvida que, se solucionada, pode me ajudar a deixar a plataforma mais robusta...

Como posso fazer o sistema ***(FEITO EM LINGUAGEM VB.NET OU C#)*** que monitora logs de key, e monitoramento desktop... Eu estou pesquisando em outros fóruns, e vi que o método **TcpCliente** *(System.Net.Sockets)* pode me ajudar a resolver isso... Alguém pode me direcionar nessa questão?